# Traveling around Schengen Area with a single entry Iceland Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, iceland, frankfurt, athens

I'm going to Iceland with a single entry "Schengen States" Visa.
On my way back to Egypt I'll pass by Frankfurt and Athens with flights. Will I face any problems regarding entering the other countries?

Answer (score 2):

You have the right visa, so your paperwork is good. Any country or particular border agent may question you but your single-entry Schengen visa allows you to enter the Schengen area exactly once. Since Iceland, Germany and Greece are all part of the area, you will only enter at your first landing point. On your way back, flying from Iceland to Frankfurt and then to Athens keeps you within the Schengen area, so do not need more than a single entry visa.

Comment: I was just worried to get the exit stamp from Iceland which means I can't get to any other Schengen areas. How can I guarantee avoiding the exit stamp in the airport?

Comment: It's not about *any* exit, it is about exiting the Schengen area which you are not. Believe me, you are not the first on to travel a Schengen country with a stopover along the way or back.

Answer (score 1):

- In principle, a single-entry Schengen visa allows you to enter the Schengen area *once* and to cross as many *internal* Schengen borders as you like. There are towns where one can easily make several dozen border crossings a day just by going for a walk.
- You explained your travel plans in your visa application and you should avoid the appearance that you misrepresented them.
  If you arrive in Athens with a visa from Iceland and plane tickets to Frankfurt and Iceland, everything will be fine since you are obviously going to Iceland.
  If you arrive in Athens with no concrete plans of onward travel, there would be questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Actually I'll pass by them on my way to Egypt, after Iceland. I was just worried to get the exit stamp from Iceland which means I can't get to any other Schengen areas. How can I guarantee avoiding the exit stamp in the airport?

Comment: You will go onto an internal Schengen flight to Frankfurt. There might be a *security* check, but no *emigration* check.